# Why does adding color to a table row increase the height?

Tags: tables, beamer, color

I'm trying to make a beamer slide containing a table with the text in a row styled in a different color. However, the row's height increases when colored, as opposed to the default. The same problem occurs if I use the `\rowfont` command. How do I correct this?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Example 1
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{blue!30}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \color{blue}{Foo} \\
        Bar\\
        Baz\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\\[1in]

    Example 2
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{blue!30}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        Foo \\
        Bar\\
        Baz\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the table to look like "Example 2", but with the row text colored as in "Example 1".

Comment: Does `\leavevmode` (before or after `\color`) help? I remember a similar case.

Comment: See the footnote on page 5 of `texdoc grfguide` (Using `textcolor` or putting `\leavevmode` or `mbox{}` before `\color` will fix it. (Sorry, it's not my fault:)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This comment was difficult to find. It deserves to be more than a comment. I have scratched my head the whole day, trying to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `textcolor`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    Example 1
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{blue!30}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \textcolor{blue}{Foo} \\
        Bar\\
        Baz\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\\[1in]

    Example 2
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{blue!30}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        Foo \\
        Bar\\
        Baz\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{blue!30}
\Body
  \hline
  \color{blue}{Foo} \\
  Bar\\
  Baz\\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]