# Text color changes height of tabular row

Tags: color, tabularx

Why is it so? My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Title.}\label{title}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{5.5cm}|X|}
    \hline
    \color{red}{\textbf{Column 1}} & \color{red}{\textbf{Column 2}} \\
    \hline
    A & a \\
    \hline  
    B & b \\
    \hline  
    C & c \\    
    \hline  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result is as follows

[image]

If color is black, then the height is as I expect:
[image]

Comment: Use `\textcolor` instead of `color`.

Comment: There must be a duplicate : http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138756/11232

Comment: more exact dup the one shown in the related links list: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31547/color-changes-cell-height-in-tabular?rq=1