# Strange behaviour of hyperref with colorlinks=true in conjunction with fancyhdr

Tags: hyperref, fancyhdr

I found something that seems like a bug in `hyperref`, namely, I'm adding clickable labels at the bottom of the page with `fancyhdr` (see tex.stackexchange.com/q/51574), and a single option in the `hypersetyp`, which should just switch between boxed and coloured links, adds an extra line if I don't add a work-around.

Edit: To make this easier to find: This **issue does not appear with pdflatex** (thanks to karlkoeller, see comments).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black  % color of internal links
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
  \markboth{\protect\hyperlink{\@currentHref}{\thesection.\ #1}}{}
}
% writes section title to \leftmark; see fancyhdr documentation. The hyperlink-construct
% is so that the fancyhdr is clickable - \@currentHref contains current link
\makeatother
\lfoot{\leftmark}\cfoot{}\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

If `colorlinks=true` is commented out, the additional line in the fancy footer disappears, as is the case when the `\sectionmark` is defined slightly differently:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
  \markboth{\hspace{0cm}\protect\hyperlink{\@currentHref}{\thesection.\ #1}}{}
}
```

I don't know whether I'm making an obvious mistake, but to me, the `colorlinks`-option shouldn't be doing that.

Edit: I'm working on an institutional machine and may not have the newest version of everything, but I asked that everything be updated a while ago for that very reason and it didn't change.
Edit2: Received response from IT, according to CTAN, fancyhdr and hyperref are up to date.

Here's a picture comparison (compiled with normal LaTeX and dvi2pdf):
[image: Without the additional line]

[image: With the additional line]

Comment: I can't reproduce any additional line.

Comment: @karlkoeller: edited my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Oh, now I understand... If I compile with pdflatex I get no additional line, if I compile with latex -> dvipdfmx I do!

Comment: Since I have a huge amount of legacy `eps`-files, I just always use Latex->dvi2pdf, so I didn't think to try pdflatex. Thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making color specials in vertical mode not affect the position of text would be a good thing, but is very hard to do in TeX. If at all possible it is best to keep them in horizontal mode (so for example `\textcolor` rather than `\color`) or here you can force the paragraph to start with `\leavevmode` or as you have `\hspace{0pt}` which is slightly less efficient but does the same job here. You could argue that hyperref should do this for you but if I was maintaining hyperref I'd be wary of changing something that could change every hyperlinked latex document ever produced:-)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It is not a huge deal since I found a work-around (and now know `\leavevmode`, too), I am mostly just curious to understand why this happens. E.g. what is "vertical mode" and why is the fancy footer in it? Why do colours affect position at all?

Comment: @Axel it's a long story, I think I put an answer on site somewhere but you will see lots of similar questions eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138756/why-does-adding-color-to-a-table-row-increase-the-height  The excuse is documented in the footnote on page 5 of grfguide in the core latex distribution (`texdoc grfguide` in texlive systems at least) basically unlike a font change a colour change is not "nothing" it inserts a node, similar to `\hbox{}` the node itself has no size but it affects things in lots of ways (most of which are bad:-)

Comment: Ok, since the source of this error is quite deep, I'll accept your answer. At least I don't have to feel like the work-around is a hack that could be removed by better understanding of the internal mechanics. Thanks!

Comment: @Axel https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/gOew1hhlxmk/CcvoVIUb8RgJ